# Getting 10.6.7 Build 10J869 installed on an 17" MacBook Pro 8,3 (Early 2011) 

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, install

I have a MacBook Pro8,3 (Early 2011) with 10.6.7 build 10J4139 installed on it and I need to get Build 10J869 installed.

Now, I can obtain a combo or delta update for build 10J869 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads, but neither seem to want to install on top of build 10J4139.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the marketing name and size for the pro 8,3? http://support.apple.com/manuals/#

Comment: It's MacBook Pro 17" early 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply installing 10J869 to an external drive? Then you could migrate the data over and finally use disk utility or deploy studio to clone the external OS back over the internal drive.

In your case, the drivers needed to properly install (or at least pass the preinstall script checking for the correct hardware) were never included in a build earlier than 10.6.6 / 10J3210

You can consult the list of builds that supported each Mac Model upon release at [Mac OS X versions (builds) for computers](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1159).

Since you are trying to get an older build running - do expect things like slow performance, odd fan behavior, graphics issues and perhaps worse if you manage to get the 10J869 build running.

At this point, you have two less than optimal avenues for getting the build on the mac you intend:

- Run the install from a mac that will run 10J869 - you can install to the MacBook Pro in target mode or use a disk tool to transfer the data.
- Modify Apple's install package to disable the check for this hardware ( or flip the comparison ) and hope the install goes well running from your mac.

Sometimes running an older version of the OS is harmless, so depending on how urgently you need this, you might give it a go and report back how it works.

Comment: I cannot seem to get 10J869 installed on an external drive using this laptop. Attempting to first install 10.6.0, for example, fails because it does not support the laptop.

Comment: As @bmike said, you need to run the install on a Mac that'll run 10J869; installing onto an external drive doesn't change the fact that you're doing the install on a model that requires 10J4139 or later.  If you don't have an older Mac available, modifying the package (which is messy and undocumented) is the only way.  Why do you need 10J869 anyway?